# android studio is not connecting with firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, config, firebase-analytics

> I am trying to setup Firebase in my android project.

> **Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.**
>
> Been looking for fixes online, most of them are removing jcenter() in build.gradle file. I don't have jcenter() or any other repository in my build.gradle.

**Heres my build gradle project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {

    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build gradle module (app):**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pabhelhasan.autowebpagerefresher2022"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


}
```

Comment: possibly it is inside some library, try to update the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to tools tab and firebase section, that will open chrome console.firebase.google.com and u connect it automatically with all the modules and imports.

Because gradle has changed and firebase didn't update the instructions, so it will not work they way you tried.